# 3D images of cells

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

You can access a lot of 3D models of ananatomical parts of the brain, for example:

https://blog.wolfram.com/2017/06/06/brain-neurons-cognition-computational-neuroscience/

Is there any way to get the same for a 3D structure of cells, such as glial cells?